# How To Start Learning Python For Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, python

I have old version of Raspberry Pi (Revision B) and now I am planning to create a robot with it. However, I don't know python at all. I want to learn python but haven't found any tutorial that teaches me Python programming for Raspberry pi. No, I am not saying I didn't find any book for RPi that teaches Python programming but those books includes readymade examples and project and such that. I want to learn every concept of python programming which uses rpio.gpio module, I want to learn to make GUI in Raspberry pi using python.

So, should I start with generic python book like 'Python the hard way' or 'A Byte of Python' ? or some other Raspberry pi centric python book ?

Enlighten me please.

Comment: Try this book (it's very particular to the Pi): http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-Python-Raspberry-Alex-Bradbury-ebook/dp/B00IG6NBCE/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1423571674&sr=8-2&keywords=python+raspberry+pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read many books about the Raspberry Pi and the one you will learn with and is complete with great examples is Simon Monk's [Programming The Raspberry Pi - Getting started with Python](http://simonmonk.org/?page_id=63). I recommend.

Comment: Thank you very much for reference. I am purchasing that book.

Answer (score 0):

Python is very easy to learn if you already know C/C++/JAVA. You can search for  online courses on Coursera or edX. Also google is your friend. :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should do both. If you want to learn every aspect of python programming, you should definitely read many books and websites. But start small. Learn how to blink a LED.

http://www.thirdeyevis.com/pi-page-2.php

Answer (score 0):

If i understand clearly, what you want is to learn python constructs specific to raspberry pi programming and it's specific libraries. But we don't have any particular book from which you can learn.

But you can learn python programming (learn basic syntax and most frequented keywords in python beforehand)on the go as you start with a project based on raspberry pi. That way you can learn quickly and there are tons of python resources on the net which you can refer.